# Company Service Provider in Estonia 'Abusive' billing practice?

Tags: contract-law

I have started a remote company in Estonia using an e-resident status back in 2020 just as Covid started to emerge putting all my plans on hold for over 2 years all the way until just a couple months ago where I decided to quit my job again to fully dedicate myself for my company. Straight to the point, me and the service provider whom I kept paying for over 2 years as my company was pretty much 'hibernating', we just decided to go sideways as I discovered unjustified limitations in their service that conflict with my company's interest. Below are the details of our last point of conflict, hoping for your help/advice:

- My first subscription to their service involved a starter subscription payment of 58 EUR back on May 22nd 2020, and they sent me a receipt by email indicating the payment covers an entire month for period May 22nd through June 22nd 2020.
- Ever since, they switched me to a professional plan (with my consent) and I started paying 94 EUR / month. Every payment was coupled with an email receipt indicating the payment covers the 22nd to the 22nd of next month period.
- I made my last 94 EUR payment on August 22nd with again an email receipt stating coverage of period going from August 22nd through September 22nd 2022.
- We have just recently decided to end my subscription, and they suggested the 30th of September as an end date which I accepted, things seemed to be going fair and smooth until...
- They asked for another full payment for September, although most of September (till the 22nd) has already been paid for back in August 22nd.
- They're justifying their claim by a second version of all invoices, accessible in their website dashboard, all stating the current month as the actual covered period with the 22nd of each month just being the payment date.
- When asked on what basis they have calculated my first payment of the starter plan (cheaper than professional plan = 58 EUR / month), they claimed their policy (nowhere documented / I have not been made aware of nor signed) dictates full month payment for clients who join before the 25th of the month.
- Extra detail just to point out an interesting coincidence: although I made my first payment on the 22nd May 2020, my company registration date was actually on May 25th 2020.
- Last, they just decided to increase their price to 106 EUR / month starting September, justifying the increase by inflation and they expect that amount from my company before they let me leave... I have expressed objection of course. As far as I'm concerned I've I already paid most of September with an email receipt from them stating my last payment covers my subscription all the way to the 22nd of September. I find the 2nd invoice in their dashboard illegitimate and purely based on greed and complete disregard to client's interest.

Would blocking their next payment until they adjust pricing for my last 8 day subscription to a proportionate amount be lawful on my side?

Thanks

---

Edit: relevant sections from the contract below:

8.7. In case any Invoice is overdue, Company shall pay a default interest of 0.1% of the outstanding
sum of the Invoice in question per each day delayed. Company shall also be obliged to cover all
additional costs (incl. legal assistance expenses) incurred by ***** or third parties related to the
collection of the overdue amounts. In addition, ***** shall be entitled to suspend the provision of
Services during the period of delay with any payment.

8.8. If Agreement is terminated or suspended, Company shall pay Service Fee pro rata to the part of
the month when Services were provided. All incurred costs shall be paid in this case in full.

8.9. ***** shall be entitled to unilaterally increase Service Fee by providing to Company
corresponding notice at least thirty (30) days in advance. If Company does not agree with increase,
it shall be entitled to terminate the Agreement. The foregoing shall not apply if Service Fee increase
is due to changes to applicable law or other regulatory reasons.

Comment: Law Stack Exchange is [for educational purposes only](http://law.stackexchange.com/help/disclaimer) and is not a substitute for individualized advice from a qualified legal practitioner. Communications on Law Stack Exchange are not privileged communications and do not create an attorney-client relationship.

Comment: I agree it is unreasonable to have the OP incur lawyer fees for something like this. The educational "value" the OP would get in exchange for that disbursement most likely will be lower than what some of us can (and do) contribute on Law SE.

Comment: Just noticed my comment got deleted without notice, is censorship a common practice in this forum? was there something wrong in my comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would blocking their next payment until they adjust pricing for my last 8 day subscription to a proportionate amount be lawful on my side?

That is risky because the provider might end up turning the tables by alleging that you defaulted on your payment(s). Instead, give the provider an ultimatum in the sense that either he fixes the bill immediately or you will withdraw your consent that the effective date of termination be the 30th of September.

Typically a party to a contract is not entitled to make belated changes unilaterally. Any amendments require approval by all parties unless they previously waived that right.

In terms of the [Restatement (Second) of Contracts](http://www.oneclubofjusticides.com/p/restatement-second-contracts.html) at §167, the agreement to extend the relation to the 30th of September is voidable by you insofar as you did not *bear the risk of mistake* (see *Restatement* at §§151 and 154) and you are the party adversely affected in that agreement. Estonian contract law likely has a similar provision. The provider did *bear the risk of mistake* by [deliberately] failing to timely inform you about the increases to your bill pursuant to the final days of September.

If you merely withhold payment until the provider adjusts the pricing for the 8-day period, the provider will foreseeably provide that service the full month of September and therewith become entitled to the remedies outlined in clause 8.7. Hence the importance of giving the aforementioned ultimatum (and of sticking to it).

Under an effective end date of September 22nd, clause 8.8 seems moot in that  you already paid, in advance, the services for the period Aug. 22nd - Sept. 22nd. The way each and every invoice indicates the period it covers disproves the provider's recent (belated) allegations of how to interpret the dates and coverage periods. But prorating to the last days of September is trickier in a context of provider's arbitrariness like the one  you describe. In part, prorating depends on when exactly the provider notified you of the increase to 106€. It seems doubtful that, under Estonian law, inflation and the provider's belated interpretations would qualify as "due to changes to applicable law or other regulatory reasons" (clause 8.9).

Note that the 30-day period mentioned in clause 8.9 refers only to the provider's notice of fee increases. The clause does not specify how far in advance the client shall give a notice of termination. Even if the contract specifies this item elsewhere, it might not apply so strictly to a scenario of announced fee increases. Most likely, the applicable criterion in this scenario would be that of *reasonableness* (and the sooner your notice of termination, the better).

The provider's other pretexts for inflating your invoice are impermissible attempts to essentially charge you a default interest much greater than 0.1% and, to a great extent, to elude its duty regarding the 30-day notice of fee increases.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer, I just took the time to read through the contract, there's no mention of the 25th of month abusive policy - updated the post with sections of the contract. The contract seems to give me right to decline a price increase on 30 day notice. Other than this I wouldn't go all the way to say they're scammers, to be fair they are the most popular service provider in Estonia and that is the actual problem, makes them feel invincible and entitled to conduct such abusive behavior. Could you please clarify what would be the risk if I decline payment after I notify them?

Comment: @ATLN "*what would be the risk if I decline payment after I notify them?*" Strictly speaking, you are safe by doing this even few days prior to the end date (whether it is the 22nd or the 30th of Sept.; but the sooner, the better) because clause 8.9 mentions the 30-day period only in regard to the provider's notice of fee increase, not the client's notice of termination. That being said, I need to make a major edit to this answer to (1) address the clauses you added, and (2) correct some inaccuracies (I had to rush with my answer before anyone completed the 5 votes that would close the post).

Comment: Perfect take your time, your help is very appreciated :)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer sir! as I'm also currently working through the process of migrating into a new provider, I'll get their opinion as well before notifying the initial provider, the need of cooperation between both to migrate accounting documents overcomplicates things,. Unfortunately sometimes doing the apparent right thing ends up leading to the wrong outcome, so will take my time to assess all aspects before taking a decision. I'll get back with an update as soon as everything gets sorted, meanwhile I don't think I can hope for a more insightful response, answer accepted.

Comment: Why would a US book on contract law be applicable in Estonia?

Comment: @DaleM Estonia being a tiny country / unheard of to most people, it would be unrealistic from me the OP, to expect a response from an Estonian law expert without paying charges superior to what's in stake. The answer is based on common sense and speculation that sound very reasonable and insightful to my eyes and perfectly satisfy my expectations. Your comment is not empty though, thanks for the remark.

Comment: @DaleM "*Why would a US book on contract law be applicable in Estonia?*" I never made that assertion. In fact, the statement "*Estonian contract law **likely** has a similar provision*" is cautious and immediately follows my citation of the *Restatement*. The explanation as premised on the *Restatement* gives the OP a hint on what to look for in --or as an aid for understanding-- Estonia's counterpart. It turns out that here the *Restatement* is consistent with Estonia's [General Part of the Civil Code Act](https://www.riigiteataja.ee/en/eli/ee/Riigikogu/act/511072022003/consolide) at §§90-93.

Comment: @ALTN As you can see from my latest comment, I was able locate the portion of Estonian law that parallels, or is consistent with, the *Restatement*. In a different situation I might just edit the third paragraph of the answer, but in this case I prefer to leave it *as is* because this and the latest comments illustrate that (1) sometimes the audience misreads answers, and (2) the multitude of parallelisms among "modern" legal systems oftentimes is overlooked. At least this time a user articulated his criticism instead of rushing to downvote this answer or close/VTC your post.

Comment: @IñakiViggers glad you came in for help, people who are open minded and look outside the box  to actually make a helpful contribution don't seem to be easily accessible on the internet (you are a rare, highly valuable breed :)), the spreading trend sadly seems to be closing doors out of incompetence and/or blind drive to get in the way for whatever dark reason. Anyhow your Estonian law-text reference is straight up to the point, will definitely use it if I end up deciding to raise the tone with my accounting provider. Big thanks again!